# Reading multiple lines of strings with spaces and delimiters in C

Tags: c

How can I read in multiple lines of data from a file in C, where each line has delimiters to separate different pieces of data on that line?

For example, I have a file with the following text:

```
Some Text | More Text | 1:23
Text Again | Even More Text | 4:56
etc...
```

This is what I have tried, but it has not worked for me so far:

```
char str1[20];
char str2[20];
int mins;
int secs;
char line[50];
while (fgets(line, 50, textFile) != 0) {
    sscanf(line, "%20[ | ]%20[ | ]%d[:]%d", str1, str2, &mins, &secs)
}
```

You can probably guess I'm new to C from my code, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Change format to `" %19[^|]|%19[^|]|%d:%d"`.  Check `if (4 == sscanf(...))` result.

Comment: fgets() returns a char*, not an integer.  in any case, suggest using: 'while( fgets( line, sizeof(line), textFile ) )'

Comment: the scanf() family of functions append a '\0' character to the resulting char string.  Therefore, the length modifier has to be one less than the max length so sscanf() does not overflow the input buffer.

Comment: Do you want `"Even More Text"` or `" Even More Text "` or is either OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
sscanf(line, "%20[ | ]%20[ | ]%d[:]%d", str1, str2, &mins, &secs)
```

with

```
sscanf(line, "%19[^|] | %19[^|] | %d:%d", str1, str2, &mins, &secs);
trim_end(str1);//remove the trailing white spaces
trim_end(str2);
```

---

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void trim_end(char *s){
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    while(len--){
        if(isspace(s[len]))
            s[len] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this still doesn't work for me, my program just crashes when it gets to this point.

Comment: Note: final `str1` may have with leading spaces, but not `str2` will not.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - `trim_end()` function inserts a NUL char not only at the end but it can also insert a NUL char in the front if there are spaces in the front?

Comment: @Nguaial It is not valid as a C-string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Lets say  `char *s = "  abc  ";`  This `trim_end()` function will convert this to "NULNULabcNULNUL".  Isn't this right?  BTW, I really enjoy  your answers.

Comment: @Nguaial That is an incorrect interpretation. Also, you can not change a string literal (the result when changing is undefined behavior)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY -  Right.  I missed the the `else break;` statement.  Thanks.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY in my opinion it would be better `while(isspace(s[--len])) {s[len]=0;}`

Comment: @nopasara Try `""` (`char str[] = ""`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY well, my bad. But anyway my comment was about the code style, `while(len && isspace(s[--len])) {s[len]=0;}` still looks better. But it's your choice.

Comment: It is the same after all.
I do not care.