# I've a text file. The text file contains strings. I wanna remove space from end of the sentence by using C programming

Tags: c, space, trim

There is some question regarding my question but I can not find the exact answer from those related questions. That's why I'm asking. Please try to understand and provide me a Function by which I will be able to get the correct answer.

I've a text file. Say it's "filename.txt" 
The file contain some strings. And at the end of every sentence there is a extra space.

**For Example: The input file:**

```
high blood sugar levels (space)
type 2 diabetes definition (space)
high blood sugar symptoms 
glucose tolerance test 
symptoms of high blood sugar
```

Here after every sentence there is an extra space. I would like to remove those spaces.

**I want to generate a output file like this:**

```
high blood sugar levels,
type 2 diabetes definition,
high blood sugar symptoms,
glucose tolerance test,
symptoms of high blood sugar
```

I've tried this, but the space is still before comma(,).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    fopen("out.txt", "w", "stdout");
    char ch, keywords[25];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("keywords.txt","r"); // read mode

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", "keywords.txt");

    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if(ch=='\n') ch=',';
        printf("%c",ch);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Please also guide me, How to print my result to a output file. I will use this simple program for my personal task. That's why I'm trying to find the result. Please help me.

Comment: You are just replacing newlines.  `fopen("out.txt", "w", "stdout");` (type as freopen?) --> `FILE *fpw = fopen("out.txt", "w");` then `fprintf(fpw, ...);`

Comment: see [end_trim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30495937/971127)

Comment: The sample input and output are confusing — you seem to mean 'end of line' more than 'end of sentence' since there isn't any punctuation in the input that is usually used to mark the end of a sentence.  You seem to want to replace newlines with commas, but the output shows newlines as well as the commas.

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/ $/,/' keywords.txt`

Comment: The first fopen line has the wrong prototype, and you ignore its return value which you need to write too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking any action on trailing white spaces (the ones that occur after a sentence is over and before the newline char '\n'). All you are doing is incorrectly trying (because you are only using `printf` which does not write to the file, so no change to your txt file anyways) trying to replace `'\n'` by a comma, which if done correctly would result in the following output containing only one line with all spaces intact:

```
high blood sugar levels (space),type 2 diabetes definition (space),high blood sugar symptoms,glucose tolerance test,symptoms of high blood sugar,
```

In order to get rid of the trailing spaces, you got to count number of spaces every time you see them and reset the count if you get a word instead of a newline. Otherwise, if you do get a newline while counting whitespace, use that count value to print that many backspaces `'\b'` followed by printing a comma. Note that you have not removed any whitespaces other than where you added comma, so newline for each line is still at the same place after trailing whitespaces. The tricky part is the corner case of no trailing space, that is `'\n'` immediately after the last char of a sentence. Inserting a comma here between the last char and newline, would requiring moving data in the file to make space for this comma. Thus, the best way would be to use a temp file, build it line by line from input file after removing trailing spaces and adding a comma. You might want to use `fgets` and `fputs`

Comment: Some more ideas are here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest you can do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int length, index;
    char *tgt = NULL;

    // open sourse file
    fp = fopen("keywords.txt","r");

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // determine length of the source file
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // allocate memory buffer
    tgt = malloc( length );

    if( tgt == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while allocating memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // initialize memory buffer
    memset( tgt, 0, length );

    // read file to memory buffer
    fread( tgt, 1, length, fp );

    // close sourse file
    fclose(fp);

    // handle contents of the source file
    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", "keywords.txt");

    index = 0;
    while( index < length && tgt[index] != '\0' )
    {
        if( tgt[index] == ' ' && index + 1 < length
                              && tgt[index + 1] == '\n' )
        {
            printf( ",\n" );        
            index += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%c", tgt[index] );
            index += 1;
        }
    }

    // release memory
    free( tgt );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Basic idea is very simple - you read the source file into memory buffer and after that you are free to do what ever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in a file line by line instead of character by character.
Then we can inspect the line to check for the space followed by newline condition and replace the space by a , (you still want the newlines, by your example).

I'd do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    FILE *in ,*out;
    ssize_t linelength;
    size_t alloc_size;
    char *line = NULL;

    if (NULL == (in = fopen("keywords.txt", "r"))){
            perror("failed to open input file\n");
            return 1;
    }
    if (NULL == (out = fopen("out.txt", "w"))){
            perror("failed to open outputfile\n");
            return 1;
    }
    while (-1 != (linelength= getline(&line, &alloc_size, in))){
            /* line contains the whole line ('\0 terminated), including    final '\n'
            the length( as a string) is linelength  */
            if (linelength < 2) continue; /* too short line */
            if (line[linelength -1] == '\n' && line[linelength-2] == ' '){
                    line[linelength-2] = ',';
            }
            fprintf(out, "%s",line);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dear Henno Brandsma,
Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately my IDE (Codeblock) is showing an error while running your code. I didn't use the function getline(). 
The error is undefined getline() Will I have to declare any headerfile like <string.h> ??? I mean which header file should be included to use getline() function? Since this is an input operation I think getline() function uses the header file <stdio.h>. Am I right? But why the error is???

Comment: It's stdio.h if you do #define _GNU_SOURCE first. Do man getline on a Linux system @ShahiduzzamanShahid